# GatsbyJs and Material-UI css is lost on page refresh

Tags: material-ui, gatsby

I have a gatsby site which runs fine on develop mode but whenever the site is built and deployed and the page is refreshed the site renders erratically.

I suspect the header component which has a window.innerwidth query is the cause.

Here is my code:

````
export default function Header(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ mobileView: true })
  const { mobileView } = state
  const classes = useStyles()

  useEffect(() => {
    const setResponsiveness = () => {
      return window.innerWidth < 900
        ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
        : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
    };

    setResponsiveness();
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
    }
  }, []);

  const MobileMenu = () => {...some code}
  const DesktopHeader = () => {...some code}
  }

  return (
    <header>
      <AppBar className={classes.root} elevation={0} position='static'>
        {mobileView ? <MobileMenu /> : <DesktopHeader />}

      </AppBar>
      
    </header>
  )

}
```

The link to the deployed site can be found here: [Working Site][1]


  [1]: https://brit-tr.com
````